# Как в цикле Python сложить в переменную две матрицы

Tags: python, матрицы

По условиям задачи мне требуется получить обратную матрицу методом Гаусса. При этом **необходимо выводить в консоль промежуточные матрицы**.

Суть метода: подставляем к заданной матрице единичную и преобразуем строки. Скрипт разделил на прямой и обратный ход.

Применил такую логику: мы преобразуем строки и всякий раз добавляем их в пустой список `bank_of_matrix`. Однако в цикле образуется шесть строк, то есть две матрицы. Сейчас они у меня в переменной `bank_of_matrix` лежат одной "кучей" строк. Необходимо их разделить.
Делать это через счетчик? Но даже если я отсчитаю нужное количество строк, как сделать отсечку, чтобы следующая "порция" строк "записывалась" в другую матрицу?

Код:

```
import numpy as np
matrix_origin = np.array([[3.8, 6.7, -1.2], 
                        [6.4, 1.3, -2.7], 
                        [2.4, -4.5, 3.5]])

n = matrix_origin.shape[0]
matrix_ = np.hstack((matrix_origin, np.eye(n)))

bank_of_matrix = []
# nrow равен номеру строки
# row содержит саму строку матрицы
for nrow, row in enumerate(matrix_):
    divider = row[nrow]  # диагональный элемент
    # делим на диагональный элемент:
    row /= divider
    bank_of_matrix.append(row) 
    # теперь вычитаем приведённую строку из всех нижележащих строк:
    for lower_row in matrix_[nrow + 1:]:
        factor = lower_row[nrow]  # элемент строки в колонке nrow
        lower_row -= factor * row  # вычитаем, чтобы получить ноль в колонке nrow
        bank_of_matrix.append(lower_row)
for i in bank_of_matrix:
    print(i)
```

И второй вопрос: пытаюсь на выводе в консоль отсечь левую матрицу с нулями и единицами. Однако ловлю ошибку.
Код:

```
for i in bank_of_matrix[:, n:]:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я верное понял вопрос чтоб был вывод промежуточных матриц, то это будет так

```
import numpy as np

matrix_origin = np.array([[3.8, 6.7, -1.2], 
                          [6.4, 1.3, -2.7], 
                          [2.4, -4.5, 3.5]])

n = matrix_origin.shape[0]
matrix_ = np.hstack((matrix_origin, np.eye(n)))

bank_of_matrix = []

for nrow, row in enumerate(matrix_):
    divider = row[nrow]  
    row /= divider
    bank_of_matrix.append(row) 
    for lower_row in matrix_[nrow + 1:]:
        factor = lower_row[nrow]  
        lower_row -= factor * row  
        bank_of_matrix.append(lower_row)

for i, matrix in enumerate(bank_of_matrix):
    print(f"Intermediate matrix {i + 1}:")
    print(matrix)
    print()


# разделяем список bank_of_matrix на две матрицы:
matrix1 = np.array(bank_of_matrix[:n])
matrix2 = np.array(bank_of_matrix[n:])

# выводим матрицу 2 без первых n столбцов:
for row in matrix2:
    print(row[n:])
```

И второй вопрос

```
for row in bank_of_matrix:
    print(row[n:])
```